# Java mongo morphia or query

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a list of id's which is part of a or statement, but the morphia query or operation has only a constructor. Can someone help me out with adding these id's in to the query.
The LIST is dynamic, it's values changes all the time. 1,2,3 is just for the sake of example

The outcome of the result should be:

> {("$or":[{"id":"1"}, {"id":2},{"id":"3"}])}

```
for (string id : ids) {
       Criteria id = query.criteria("id").equals(id);
       query.or(id)
 }


for (string id : ids) {
     Criteria id  = query.criteria("id").equals(id);
       query.or.add(id)
 }
```

Comment: You can use `org.mongodb.morphia.query.FieldEnd#in` like so:

`query.criteria("id").in(asList("1", "2", "3"))`

It's not an `or` as such but gets you what you want, i think.

Comment: yea thanks, i could figure it out with $in operator. thnx for the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the sulotion. the Morphia query dosnt allow it, but i used $in operator 
in a BasicDBObject as you can see in here in below:

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
ids.add("3)
BasicDBObject basicObject = new BasicObject("$in", list);
query.filter("id", basicObject);
```

so the main point is that i use In instead of Or.
And the outcome will be

```
{id:{"$in":["1","2","3"]}}
```

Comment: You can use `org.mongodb.morphia.query.FieldEnd#in` like so:

`query.criteria("id").in(asList("1", "2", "3"))`

Comment: That is also an option yea :) thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
Query<YourEntity> query = datastore.find(YourEntity.class);            

query.or(
  query.criteria("id").equal("1"),
  query.criteria("id").equal("2"),
  query.criteria("id").equal("3")
);

List<YourEntity> result = query.asList();
```

**Update:** For dynamic try following (not tested):

```
Query<YourEntity> query = datastore.find(YourEntity.class);            

for(int i = 0; i < yourArrayOfObjects.length; i++){
  query.or(
    query.criteria("id").equal(yourArrayOfObjects[i].getId()),
  );
}

List<YourEntity> result = query.asList();
```

You should be able to chain different MongoDB query operations togehter

Comment: Thnx for the answer, i might have added to my question that the list is dynamic. so it's values can change.

Comment: Hi Rieckpil, i have tried you code and this is the result what i got : 
{ "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ { "_id" : "1"}]} , { "$or" : [ { "_id" : "2"}]} , { "$or" : [ { "_id" : "3"}]}]}
It has added the or 3 times in the query